# What is the RESTful way of representing grouped data?

Tags: rest, json-api

Assume we have the following table **posts** with the following columns

`| id | title | likes | created_at | user_id |`

Now, if I want to group the posts by `user_id` I'd do

`api/posts?group_by=user_id`

But what would be the format of response

should it be

```
{
  "results": [{
    "1": [ // because we grouped by id
      {id: 1, title: "some title", likes: 12 ...}
      ...
    ] 
  }]
}
```

OR should it be

```
{
  results: [{
    "user_id": 1
      "posts": [
        {id: 1, title: "some title", likes: 12 ...}
        ...
      ] 
  }]
}
```

And then how do we perform multi column grouping? Also how should we query & representing aggregate information ?

Comment: As a response already contains the semantics of results, this field is a bit redundant in my opinion. Usually you return the same structure with filtered content as you would with returning ungrouped/filtered results. That being said, REST is no protocol but a style. Therefore it's up to you what you prefer. For a client it may be less work to collect all posts belonging to one person if they are already grouped within a `user_id`, however, client and server have to treat that case differently than un-grouped/filtered requests

Comment: I see, but is there an example? I mean I want to follow the widely used format for grouping